# C# and parameterized SQLite, WITHOUT going through ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sqlite, parameterized

Is it possible, and if so, how...  To do parameterized queries with SQLite WITHOUT having to go through ADO.NET.  I've been asked to do some testing with SQLite for a project that needs to have a zero-admin install... ie: no special permissions, things added to windows registry, etc.  I would suspect that using an ADO.NET would require such, even though SQLite is just a DLL sitting in the project directory.

And yes, I do understand the importance of parameterized queries and issues that can arise out of SQL-Injection if not handled safely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What makes you think that ADO.NET would require registry entries etc? It doesn't. You just need .NET installed and the appropriate provider assembly.

Now, you won't need *all* of ADO.NET - for instance, you may well not need the `DataTable`/`DataSet` support, if you're happy to use the appropriate `DataReader` type yourself - but again, if you *do* want to use them (even strongly typed versions) you shouldn't need any special settings.

Of course, it's *possible* that the SQLite provider has its own requirements around the registry, but I *very* much doubt it. That would go against my "normal" ADO.NET provider experience, as well as being against the normal usage of SQLite.

I expect there are various SQLite providers. For instance, there's [one here](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) which combines the .NET part *and* the native code of SQLite itself, so there's just the single DLL to deploy alongside your application, as far as I can tell. It doesn't get much simpler than that.

Comment: Its working, but I had to go to SourceForge to get a copy, and ultimately had to run its setup...  I guess if its all a go, we can find out what specifically needs to be deployed.  Thanks